# fontFamily in FragmentActivity doesn't work

Tags: android, android-layout, textview, android-fonts

I created a simple dummy project in Android Studio 3.5.1 with 2 activitites. You can download it here: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1OXlyjk_NYHLQLa3uxw_twE4A5CkBLtEr

One activity is AppCompatActivity, the second one is FragmentActivity. Both activities contain TextView with android:fontFamily set to a new font.

When launched, AppCompatActivity's TextView uses that new font, but the FragmentActivity's TextView still uses default font.

Should I report this as a bug? Or is this a bad way to set fontFamily? Can you please show me a reliable way how to set fontFamily for textView inside FramgmentActivity.

Comment: Hello, have you found a solution to this issue?